real analytic function - a real analytic function coincides with its power series at a point within the radius of convergence.
Is it true that a real analytic function coincides with its power series expansion at a point within the radius of convergence?
To formally put it:
Let $f$ be a real analytic function on some open set $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n$ the power series expansion of it at $x_0\in D$, $R>0$ be the radius of convergence of the power series, is it true that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n$ for all $x\in(x_0-R,x_0+R)\cap D$?
Being real analytic only guarantees $f$ coincides with the power series locally, so I would like to know whether this can be extended to the whole radius of convergence of the series.

this is a general result that follows from the identity theorem as long as $D$ is connected (so an interval) since if $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n$ then $g=f$ on an open nontrivial set in $(x_0-R,x_0+R)\cap D$ (which is an interval if $D$ interval) so $g=f$ everywhere there; note that if $D$ is not an interval then the result is false since you can make $f$ from two pieces on two disjoint intervals and each piece can for example have infinity radius
